# 10 second interval using stopwatch

Tags: c#

I have a piece of code that uses stopwatch, but I would be able to be run some logic every 10 seconds by using the stopwatch class. Unfortunately, I am not sure the best way to do this. Basically, this is what I am trying to do:

```
Stopwatch.start();

if(Stopwatch == 10seconds)

  Do something here!

Else
  Do something else!
```

Can anyone help??

Comment: The StopWatch is not a Timer. Use a Timer if you need regular events.

Comment: Use the tick event: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Why aren't you using the Timer class instead?

Comment: I am not raising an event - I am only looking for 10 second intervals. i.e. 10, 20, 30 seconds.

Comment: @Andy5: Yes, and the correct way to do that is by having a `Timer` raise an event. You have not explained why you cannot do this using a `Timer` (i.e., why an event-based solution won't work).

Comment: if you just want the code to wait for 10 seconds, use Thread.Sleep(...)

Comment: @Muad'Dib: That is abusing `Thread.Sleep`.  `Thread.Sleep` is not an accurate way to handle timing; it might wait longer than planned.  Though it's still less horrifying than polling in a `while` loop.

Comment: @Brian true, but the timer could wait longer too.  from the OP's reaction to the timer event, this might be closer to the behavior he wants.

Comment: Why hasn't anyone suggested using a Timer?

Comment: @Muad'Dib: Any time you see Thread.Sleep in production code, that should set off a red flag. That is almost certainly the wrong solution in all but the most trivial cases. Threads that are sleeping are not doing *any* work; typically you want a thread to keep on doing useful work in the forty billion machine cycles the user is waiting for.

Comment: @EricLippert I agree. I would never use this in production code. the OP seems adverse to the event model of Timer, just offering a possible alternative--not necessarily a viable one

Answer (score 16):

That is not at all what StopWatch is for; stopwatch is for doing high-precision timing for performance testing. That's why it is in the Diagnostics namespace.

If you want something to happen every ten seconds then create a Timer and create an event handler for the tick event. The event handler will be called every time the timer goes off.

Comment: I am not raising an event - I am just looking for 10 second intervals

Comment: @Andy5: I don't know how any of us can be much more clear. You want something to happen every ten seconds. Make a timer, set it to go off every ten seconds, handle the event. If you have some really good reason to *not do things the correct and standard way* then it would be helpful if you'd tell us what that reason is rather than just arguing.

Answer (score 11):

This isn't what the Stopwatch class is meant for.  Use a [System.Timer.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx) and subscribe to the [Elapsed event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.elapsed.aspx).

Comment: I am not raising an event - I am just looking for 10 second intervals

Comment: @Andy5:  _You_ aren't raising an event with this suggestion either; you're _subscribing_ to the Timer's Elapsed event so that every 10 seconds, your code executes.

Comment: Replying to all the answers with the same comment just shows that you actually don't understand what people are suggesting. If your need is to do 'something' every 10 seconds, Timer is the perfect solution. Please try out the sample code posted by Fuex and see if it meets your needs.

Answer (score 3):

you should use the [DispatcherTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx) class.

sample code from the MSDN docs:

```
//  DispatcherTimer setup
dispatcherTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0,0,1);
dispatcherTimer.Start();

//  System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer.Tick handler
//
//  Updates the current seconds display and calls
//  InvalidateRequerySuggested on the CommandManager to force 
//  the Command to raise the CanExecuteChanged event.
private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Updating the Label which displays the current second
    lblSeconds.Content = DateTime.Now.Second;

    // Forcing the CommandManager to raise the RequerySuggested event
    CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
}
```

of course, you would want to change the timespan to 10 seconds:

```
dispatcherTimer.Interval = New TimeSpan(0,0,10);
```

if, on the other hand, you want your code to just sit there and do nothing, so to speak, for 10 seconds, you can use `Thread.Sleep( new TimeSpan(0,0,10) )` however, you should avoid this option. it is not, normally, a Good Thing (tm) [MSDN for thread.sleep is here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d00bd51t.aspx)

Comment: This is not really useful on a WinForm project.

Comment: dont see anything that says WinForms anywhere

Comment: @Otiel true :) the code is from the MSDN which you can set to either/or

Comment: I am not raising an event - I am just looking for 10 second intervals

Comment: the timer will raise the event every 10 seconds (or whatever your interval is) when it does so, you call a method or exercise whatever code you like in the event. this is the way timers work in .net

Answer (score 1):

Use a [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx) instead. Have a look a the liked MSDN page - it contains a complete example.

Edit: It's not clear what you want to do. If you simply want your code to wait for ten seconds, then you could use [System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d00bd51t.aspx).

Comment: I am not raising an event - I am just looking for 10 second intervals

Answer (score 1):

```
       System.Timers.Timer timer;

       //Set Timer
       timer = new Sytem.Timers.Timer();
       timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_tick);
       timer.Interval = 10000; //10000 ms = 10 seconds
       timer.Enabled = true;


       public void timer_tick(object source, EventArgs e)
       {
             //Here what would you like to do every 10000 ms
       }
```

Comment: I am not raising an event - I am just looking for 10 second intervals

Comment: @Andy5 If you are looking for 10 second intervals you need this, so If you are trying to do something else, please explain, don't post the same answer to everyone... Cheers.